# POSTGRES: expected DEFAULT expression to have type varchar, but '0' has type int

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to do a 3rd party software installation and I'm getting the error:

```
SQL Error DB_ERROR_ERROR: XXUUU: expected DEFAULT expression to have type varchar, but '0' has type int ERROR: XXUUU: expected DEFAULT expression to have type varchar, but '0' has type int
```

The query that the installation is trying to execute is:

```
Executed query : create table llx_adherent_type_lang ( rowid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, fk_type integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, lang varchar(5) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, label varchar(255) NOT NULL, description text, email text, import_key varchar(14) DEFAULT NULL );
```

My guess is that the problem has to do with `lang varchar(5) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL` part of the query? Is it because the column is expecting a `varchar(5)` while the default value is `0`? Which is an integer? Is my way of thinking valid?

If I am to fix it does it mean that I just need to find where the query is and change the default value from `0` to `"0"`?

Comment: `'0'` rather than `"0"`, but yes your reasoning is correct. Or maybe better `''`? I'd recommend to ask the software supplier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it from `0` to `'0'`, or as Bengi suggests `''` if that makes more sense.

In  postgresql `"0"` would be a name (could be used for the name of a table or name of a column etc) but `'0'` is a string literal(text, char, varchar, etc)